# Silverlight pausing when browser is minimized

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

It seems like a default behavior to pause the silverlight application when it is minimized.  Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't pause, the UI thread gets throttled to a much lower update rate. If you are doing something that needs to be executed in the background then you should move it out of the UI thread.